# custom search bar using UISearchController in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8

I have a custom search bar class, and I used interface builder to insert a search bar as an instance of this custom class. How do I use this search bar is search bar for the UISearchController? Its searchBar property is read-only so I can't assign my search bar to it.

Comment: `UIAlertController`? Did you mean `UISearchController`?

Comment: @rmaddy yep sorry! edited

Comment: was this able to help you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your already initialized custom search bar to be returned in the overriden search bar getter for you custom UISearchController class and setup its properties after the searchcontroller init, this way all the UISearchController functionality are retained:

```
public class DSearchController: UISearchController {

    private var customSearchBar = DSearchBar()
    override public var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        get {
            return customSearchBar
        }
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
    public init(searchResultsController: UIViewController?,
                searchResultsUpdater: UISearchResultsUpdating?,
                delegate: UISearchControllerDelegate?,
                dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation: Bool,
                hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation: Bool,
                searchBarDelegate: UISearchBarDelegate?,
                searchBarFrame: CGRect?,
                searchBarStyle: UISearchBarStyle,
                searchBarPlaceHolder: String,
                searchBarFont: UIFont?,
                searchBarTextColor: UIColor?,
                searchBarBarTintColor: UIColor?, // Bar background
                searchBarTintColor: UIColor) { // Cursor and bottom line

        super.init(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)

        self.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsUpdater
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation
        self.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation        

        customSearchBar.setUp(searchBarDelegate,
                              frame: searchBarFrame,
                              barStyle: searchBarStyle,
                              placeholder: searchBarPlaceHolder,
                              font: searchBarFont,
                              textColor: searchBarTextColor,
                              barTintColor: searchBarBarTintColor,
                              tintColor: searchBarTintColor)

    }
}
```

And this is my custom searchBar:

```
public class DSearchBar: UISearchBar {

    var preferredFont: UIFont?
    var preferredTextColor: UIColor?

    init(){
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    func setUp(delegate: UISearchBarDelegate?,
               frame: CGRect?,
               barStyle: UISearchBarStyle,
               placeholder: String,
               font: UIFont?,
               textColor: UIColor?,
               barTintColor: UIColor?,
               tintColor: UIColor?) {

        self.delegate = delegate
        self.frame = frame ?? self.frame
        self.searchBarStyle = searchBarStyle
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.preferredFont = font
        self.preferredTextColor = textColor
        self.barTintColor = barTintColor ?? self.barTintColor
        self.tintColor = tintColor ?? self.tintColor
        self.bottomLineColor = tintColor ?? UIColor.clearColor()

        sizeToFit()

        //        translucent = false
        //        showsBookmarkButton = false
        //        showsCancelButton = true
        //        setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
        //        customSearchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    let bottomLine = CAShapeLayer()
    var bottomLineColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        for view in subviews {
            if let searchField = view as? UITextField { setSearchFieldAppearance(searchField); break }
            else {
                for sView in view.subviews {
                    if let searchField = sView as? UITextField { setSearchFieldAppearance(searchField); break }
                }
            }
        }

        bottomLine.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0.0, frame.size.height - 1, frame.size.width, 1.0)).CGPath
        bottomLine.fillColor = bottomLineColor.CGColor
        layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
    }

    func setSearchFieldAppearance(searchField: UITextField) {
        searchField.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, frame.size.width - 10.0, frame.size.height - 10.0)
        searchField.font = preferredFont ?? searchField.font
        searchField.textColor = preferredTextColor ?? searchField.textColor
        //searchField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        //backgroundImage = UIImage()
    }

}
```

Init example:

```
searchController = DSearchController(searchResultsController: ls,
                                     searchResultsUpdater: self,
                                     delegate: self,
                                     dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation: true,
                                     hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation: true,
                                     searchBarDelegate: ls,
                                     searchBarFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 44.0),
                                     searchBarStyle: .Minimal,
                                     searchBarPlaceHolder: NSLocalizedString("Search a location...", comment: ""),
                                     searchBarFont: nil,
                                     searchBarTextColor: nil,
                                     searchBarBarTintColor: UIColor.whiteColor(),
                                     searchBarTintColor: iconsColor)
searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .Dark
definesPresentationContext = true
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```